# Is it possible for Gridview to Display XML Element Name?

Tags: xml, aspxgridview

I have an xml file having the following structure

```
<companies>
    <company>
        <CompanyName>CompanyA</CompanyName>
        <tel>123</tel>
    </company>
    <company>
        <CompanyName>CompanyB</CompanyName>
        <tel>456</tel>
    </company>
</companies>
```

I want to use inline code

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Companies.xml" XPath="Companies/Company/CompanyName"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="text()" HeaderText="Company Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

But it doesn't work. I know DataField is supposed to be an attribute name. Can it be an inner text value? What should I put there?

Answer (score 0):

I found a only way to do it is

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Companies.xml" XPath="Company"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" XPath="Companies/Company">
    <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#XPath("FirstName") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```